# Anchor goes to whole width when centered

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've one paragraph and one button in my container like this

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <p class="text-center text-muted">text</p>
          <a class="btn btn-danger  center" href="">
            Download PDF 
         </a > 
       </div>            
 </div>
```

code for my center class is

```
.center{
    display: block !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

and this is how output  looks like while i was expecting to be in center with small button that should be wide as per its value like Download Pdf

[image]

Comment: what if you add somthing like this: .center { width: 200px; } ?

Comment: yes that will work but is it standard approach ?

Comment: it depends on the rest of your styles: I think your btn was inheriting width: 100%;

Comment: ok there is no button  with center class so at the moment its fine , Thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

Your style should be like:

```
.center {
    display: block !important;
    width: 250px; //change accordingly;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

Margin auto works well with fixed width container.

Or try:

```
<div style='text-align:center'>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="">
        Download PDF 
    </a >
</div>
```

Just an advice, avoid using too many `!important`